# Ramification locus of double cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\pi: X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is a double cover ramified over a smooth curve $C\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ of degree $d$.

Let $R$ be the ramification locus of $\pi$. We know $\pi^{*}C=2R$. Is it true that $R$ is linearly equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}\pi^{*}C\sim \frac{d}{2}\pi^{*}L$, where $L$ is a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$? From what I've written, I only see that $R$ and $\frac{1}{2}\pi^{*}C$ differ by 2-torsion.

(Here, we know $d$ is even since $R^2=\frac{(\pi^{*}C)^2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}C^2=\frac{d^2}{2}$ is an integer.)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Why can't $\frac{1}{2}\pi^{*}C$ and $R$ differ by 2-torsion? I know $Pic(X)$ is discrete, so it seems very likely that it can't... (I'm going to edit the question to make it more obvious what I'm asking now)

Comment: Let me denote $\frac12 C$ by $D$. Then $X = Spec_{P^2}(O \oplus O(-D))$ with the structure of algebra given by $O(-D)\otimes O(-D) \cong O(-2D) \cong O(-C) \to O$. Therefore $H^0(X,\pi^*O(D)) = H^0(P^2,\pi_*\pi^*O(D)) = H^0(P^2,O(D) \otimes \pi_*O_X) = H^0(P^2, O(D) \oplus O)$. The global section corresponding to 1 in the second summand is the equation of the ramification divisor.